# Where can one convert their bitcoins to Liquid LBTC bitcoins on Blockstreams Liquid Network?

Tags: blockstream, liquid

Is there a place where one can convert their Bitcoin to Liquid BTC? Which exchanges? Is there even a mobile wallet that supports it if one wants to withdraw it?

Answer (score 2):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.blockstream.com/liquid/technical_overview.html), anyone running a Liquid node can generate and fund a peg-in transaction. And anyone can run a Liquid node.

You'll need a participant, which can be an exchange, to peg-out and exchange your L-BTC for BTC though.

The peg-in is explained in more details [here](https://docs.blockstream.com/liquid/acquire_lbtc.html).